# Storing variables in a public file

Tags: file, uitableview, variables, store, public

I need a way to store a variable in a public file, so i can access it within other classes, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you can read and write to the file, it is possible to store a variable there. But it also depends what language you are talking about and what code you are trying change. It would be helpful if we saw some existing code in the file that you attempt to write.